# Whitelist for Streamlit

Tags: streamlit

Due to security concerns, I have set up my streamlit server to only allow access from specific IP addresses. I have searched Google, chatgpt, and the official documentation, but I have not been able to find the instructions on how to do this.

and also i cannot find whitelist options on config file.

If you have any information, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Streamlit doesn't natively support allow-listing traffic from specific servers.